# How can I remove all the customizations imposed by Linux Mint 17.1 on firefox?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firefox, linux-mint

I have found two solutions for the same:

1. Downloading and installing .tar.bz2 package (firefox) from mozilla.org (**Problem**:Package provided is portable and is not installable).
2. Installing firefox from ubuntu's repository (**Problem**: Will there be any compatiblity issues? I don't even know if it is possible?)

Answer (score 0):

As per point 1) what is portable and not installable?  if you download the tarball  do this:

1)   cd {some  folder you want to use ---assuming ~/Downloads is not ok}

2)   tar -xvf /path/to/firefox tarball

3) once  untarred  look in that folder for for the .deb file and install normally  OR with dpkg (for ex.  sudo apt install /path/to/firefox.deb OR sudo dpkg -i /path/to/firefox.deb)

Comment: Sorry, if I could not explain it properly, probably due to my bad english.
The tarball do not contain any .deb package. It directly contain executable and necessary library files of firefox.

Comment: then run the executable and create a symlink to it to use it normally     e.g. user@mint ~$ /usr/bin/firefox  &  and ln -s /location of executable  /usr/bin/

Comment: Anyways this new firefox won't get any updates (with sudo apt-get dist-upgrade), I guess, as the package manager is unaware of this firefox.

Comment: correct there its a separate install as apt-get/dpkg never installed it

Comment: But is there any way to install ubuntu's version of firefox, at least it isn't that much customized. After all, Linux Mint is derived from Ubuntu.

Comment: yes install it then pull the unity crap out  with apt-get remove or synaptic   the unity-extensions et all is what is causing the uglyness